# dictionary behaves as an ordered collecttion

Tags: c#, dictionary

I've read about the `Dictionary` type that it's not an ordered collection (because it's a KVP). But I have the following code:

```
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<Func<bool>, string>
        {
            { () => true, "first" },
            { () => true, "second" }
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dictionary.First(f => f.Key()).Value);
        }
```

And the above code prints only the string "first". Why doesn't it print and the "second" string if the collection it's not ordered?

Comment: Because, in the loop it will print the first value of the dictionary. Instead if you use a dictionary[i] or foreach then you can print all.

Comment: Very strange question to be honest. What does the for 0 to 40 loop do? I don't see any purpose. Also why do you use a Func<> as Key? Never seen that.

Comment: I'm using a Func because I can't have two keys with the value true. And in the loop, I'm getting the first value with the key that returns true. I just want to understand this behavior

Comment: @Chidambaram From msdn site: For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

Comment: No one has said that a dictionary doesn't behave like an ordered collection. It's just not guaranteed. In the current implementation the order is stable until you don't remove items.

Comment: *"I'm using a Func because I can't have two keys with the value true."* It looks like you don't have a clear idea about what you want to do and how a dictionary behaves. Do yourself a favor and don't just write *some* code. **Never** add anything to your program when you are not 100% sure about what it does.

Comment: @BudaGavril The documentation is correct. Your test happens to run one way.

Comment: Check out some of the explanations for C++ unordered_map storage if you can't find anything on Dictionary.  It can end up being pretty random. I'm not sure Dictionary behaves the same way, but an implementation of it COULD without breaking the interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `KeyValuePair` is not the reason why the `Dictionary` is unordered. The `SortedDictionary` uses also `KeyValuePair` but is ordered because that one is implemented as a balanced black red binary tree. The `Dictionary` is implemented as hash map. So the order depends on the hash value generated by the key `object` and the number of buckets. In your case it has always the same order because both of your key elements `var key = new Func<bool>(() => true)` are generating the same hash code. You can check it with `GetHashCode()`. If two keys have the same hash code they will be added to the same bucket. And each bucket is simply a list with the order of the items in which they are added.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.

Comment: "_(for dictionary)...the order depends on the hash value generated by the key_": that's not true: see [this sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d5Q2Ru). The order of elements within a dictionary is an implementation detail subject to change in future versions, and right now seems to be the order of insertion.

Comment: You have to read the whole sentence "So the order depends on the hash value generated by the key object and the number of buckets.". The bucket is chosen by GetHashCode % NumberOfBuckets.

Comment: in my sample, the keys are random integers (for which GetHasCode returns the integers itself), and it seems that the order depends on order insertion, non on hash code of the keys. I'm talking about order of enumeration of a dictionary, which seems to be the only meaningful meaning of "order" for a dictionary. @StefanKirsch, am I missing something?

Comment: Yes its true. Now i got it. I have checked the implementation and there is a list where the items will be added according to the order of adding. But it will not have that order if you remove some items and then add them again. The new items will get the place of a deleted item. So if you delete the first item and add a new one. The last added item will be the first.

Answer (score 0):

why should it print "second"? 
`First` returns one and one only element satisfying the condition.

It internally loop throght all elements (in an order unspecified, I assume), and stop when the condition is met.

So in your case the  `() => true, "first"` pair happens to be the first tested. it returns true and therefore is returned

[This sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d5Q2Ru) show the order of enumeration (which is very likely the same order of testing condition within First): as other have pointed out, and as stated in MSDN, this order is undefined: it is an implementation detail that can change in future version of .Net framework

Comment: from msdn: For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

Comment: so if the order is undefined, why I'm always getting only the first element?

Comment: @BudaGavril Because that's an implementation detail. A new version of .Net could change that.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I see. Thanks

Comment: @BudaGavril see [this sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PO0rjO): it shows that elements seems to be enumerated in the same order they are inserted in dictionary, but as Matthew Watson says, the order is an implementation detail subject to change, so never count on it

Comment: and [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d5Q2Ru) sample as well showing the order of evaluation of testing the condition